# duplicate model instance with all related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

**EDIT**:
it works fine this way

---

I'm trying to clone a model instance with all the related objects.

I have two models :

```
class VersionContrat(models.Model):

    nom_version = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

and :

```
class Vacation (models.Model):

    poste_travail = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    version_contrat = models.ForeignKey(VersionContrat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=9)

    date_debut = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried this method in VersionContrat to copy a VersionContrat object and all the Vacation objects related with the foreign key:

```
def duplicate(self):
    vacations = Vacation.objects.filter(version_contrat=self)
    self.pk = None
    self.version = int(self.version)+1
    self.save()

    for vacation in vacations:
        vacation.pk = None
        vacation.version_contrat = self
        vacation.save()

    return print('clone to {}'.format(self))
```

But it doesn't work and I can't find out why, anyone has an idea why ?

Comment: what problem did you face actually? I tried with your code, and it worked for me

Comment: Well I tried again and now it works, maybe my server wasn't up to date